# iOS UITableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath not reacting for clicks everywhere

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue

I have several `UITableViews` which should segue further in my navigation controller. First I've created the segues directly from the table view cells. But then I've noticed that in the smaller cells if you click on the label or somewhere, this method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` doesn't get triggered. Only if you click on an "empty" space in the cell.
So I've created the segue for the whole view and just called `performSegueWithIdentifier` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

But still the same problem. Is this only my impression that you have to click on empty parts or onto the right side of a cell to perform a segue or is something else wrong? Or how could I make the whole cell reactive?

Answer (score 0):

You might try turning off `User interaction enabled` for the labels in your cell.